# how can i choose which lines to print in file in java?

Tags: java

i have this file name **input.txt**:

```
3 1

Hoa Lac, Thang Long, Le Quang Dao, Me Tri, Pham Hung, My Dinh, Cau Giay, Kim Ma, Hoan Kiem

Bus 74, Price 9000, Hoa Lac, Thang Long, Le Quang Dao, Me Tri, Pham Hung, My Dinh

Bus 99, Price 50000, Hoa Lac, My Dinh

Bus 34, Price 7000, My Dinh, Cau Giay, Kim Ma, Hoan Kiem

From: Hoa Lac, To: Hoan Kiem
```

i want to try to store each line as a String in array and i have write like this

```
  public static void readFile(){
        try {
            String data[] = new String[100];
            File myObj = new File("input.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            int m;
            int n;
            m = myReader.nextInt();
            n = myReader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("m = " + m);
            System.out.println("n = " + n);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()){
                int i = 0;
                data[i] = myReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data[i]);                
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("cannot find file!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

so far i can only read file and display all of them at once, but i can not control which line i want to print(ex:i want to print only line: 2 3 4),  please help me and explain to me please.

Comment: You could read all the lines into your array, without printing them, and then have a `for` loop which prints only the lines you want. Or you could put your `println` in an `if` statement which checks the value of `i`.

Comment: By the way, please step through your code with the debugger, or add some more logging, and check that `i` is behaving as you expect.

Comment: so i tries to store each line into data[i] and i++, and i remove the println in while loop, and try to `System.out.println(data[i]);` outside the loop, and i try 0 1 2 3 4 and the result is only "From: Hoa Lac, To: Hoan Kiem" line is stored in index number 1, all of the rest is display NULL why is this happening ?

Comment: The line `int i = 0;` creates a new variable, initialised to 0, for each iteration of your while loop. Move it before the loop.